# How to call notifyDataSetChanged() from custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a custom ListView in which every item is divided into two parts.One is description and other is delete button.So from my getView() method of adapter I am setting onClickListener() on both.If user clicks on description part then it will open a new activity and if user clicks on delete button the the list item get deleted.My problem is that I am not able to refresh list at that point after deleting item from listview.I dont know from where and how to call notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter so that it refreshes my listview.

My getView() method of adapter looks like this:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     ViewHolder holder = null;
     if (convertView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
         convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();

         holder.listCount = (TextView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.listCount);
         holder.Number = (TextView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.Value);
         holder.journey = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.journey);
         holder.Item = (RelativeLayout) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.Item);
         holder.delete = (LinearLayout) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.delete);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }
     p = getItem(position);

     holder.listCount.setText(position + 1 + ".");
     holder.Number.setText(p.getNumber());
     holder.journey.setText(p.getPoint() + "-" +
         p.getUpto());
     holder.Item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Point pp = pLists.get(position);
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, abc.class);
             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
             bundle.putString("Number", p.getNumber());
             bundle.putBoolean("isInDatabase", true);
             intent.putExtras(bundle);
             context.startActivity(intent);
         }
     });

     holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             new deletingSelected().execute(pLists.get(position).get_id());
         }
     });
     return convertView;
 }
```

The item got deleted through OnClick but where should I put code for notifyDataSetChanged() here?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onClick after deletion call notifyDataSetChanged()